# H2 Database Clean Up Event Like MySQL

Tags: h2

Is there a feature with the H2 database that does the equivalent of the following EVENT in MySQL?

```
CREATE EVENT `expire_reservations`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2023-01-01 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO reservation_expired (SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE reservation.expiryDatetime <= NOW());
    DELETE FROM reservation WHERE reservation.expiryDatetime <= NOW();
  END;;
```

So basically, I'm looking for some function that can do a clean up of a certain table and throw away some events that are older than this certain date.